# Single Signon Mechanism with AWS for multiple customers, some want SSO, some don't

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on

We have a site for our customers to log onto to get their relevant data. We have set it up on AWS using Cognito for user authentication. Each customer navigates to the same URL, enters their credentials, and then gets shown their own information. One of our customers has a corporate policy for any SaaS offering requiring a SSO (using SAML2.0). Our other customers do not need the SSO mechanism.

I have read through the documents AWS provides: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/index.html) but these appear to be focused on a single corporation with AWS accounts for services provided by AWS. I have not been able to find any articles that address the situation.

Specific questions I have:

1. Is the AWS SSO mechanism the correct mechanism to use to achieve the goals? I have read in one Q&A that it is better to manipulate this through Cognito (but I cannot find the relevant article to link here).
2. If we set up one company to use SSO, can other companies use the credentials we set up to go to the same site?
3. Can we set up multiple companies to use the SSO separately, or will the application of a second SAML overwrite the first? (this doesn't seem likely as their would be updates to applicable users).

Any articles that can help point me in the best direction is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS SSO would be a different AWS service you would have to integrate your application with.

If you're already using Cognito, you should be adding their SAML provider as [a Cognito identity pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/saml-identity-provider.html) instead of adding AWS SSO.

Comment: Thanks I read this article, but then I think I confused myself by reading the SSO documents.  In the blog, it says that I can set up multiple organizations to use the endpoints.